# Error in simple function call in Wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to insert a secondary header beyond the main.
the main thing is `header.php` and call with `get_header();`

To try to make another header I added in functions.php:

```
function secondary_header() {
  echo '<p>This is a test</p>';
}
add_action('get_customheader', 'secondary_header');
```

and in the page.php

```
get_customheader();
```

I have the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_customheader()
```

Answer (score 2):

As the [Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Headers) say "*Custom header is an image that is chosen as the representative image in the theme top header section.*"

So, this function is expecting an array of default arguments to render the image, like "width", "height", "default-image" (image location/path).

This means your problem is one of the followings:

- You are using an unnecessary function for what you want to accomplish.
- You want to use the **Custom Hearder** function, but don't understand how it works.

To make it work you just need to delete this line:

```
add_action('get_customheader', 'secondary_header');
```

And then call your function on your template file like any other normal function:

```
<?php secondary_header(); ?>
```

If what you want is to insert additional code/html in multiple pages dynamically or just to keep your documents neat and clean, I'll recommend you to learn about the built-in function of Wordpress to insert template files, which is **[get_template_part()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part)**.

For further understanding of how **get_template_part()** works I'll recommend you to learn about **include()** and **require()** which are native PHP functions and will work even outside of WP.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be easier for you to create a .php file with your custom header, and then just pull it in your template file where you call `get_header()` with something like

```
get_template_part('additional/custom_header');
```

This will search the `custom_header.php` file in the 'additional' folder of your theme.

Your error comes from the fact that you have added an action to a non existing function `get_customheader()`. What you wanted probably is `do_action('get_customheader');`

Read more:

[do_action()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action)

[add_action()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action)